# Excel formula LIKE, AND, IF, WILDCARDS

Tags: excel

I have a scenario where I am using a number of formulas I am comfortable with together and not getting a result. I want to get ANY result where there is a "1" present in a cell. (The 1 is the result of a formula). As well as where the text of a certain column contains an &. ("&/OR")

I have tried a couple formulas

```
=IF(AND(I1=1,C2="*"&$Q$1&"*"),1," ")
```

---In this I have tried to put the & in a cell and refer to it

```
=IF(I1=1,1," ")
```

and then in a new column

```
=IF(C2="*"&"/"&"*",1," ")
```

Then combining the results of the two? Is anyone noticing what is wrong with it??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wildcards aren't recognised with comparison operators like `=`, for example if you use this formula

`=A1="*&*"`

that will treat the `*`'s as literal asterisks (not wildcards) so that will only return `TRUE` if A1 literally contains `*&*`

You can use `COUNTIF` function, even for a single cell, e.g.

`=COUNTIF(A1,"*&*")`

That will return 1 if A1 contains `&`, so for your purposes:

`=IF(AND(I1=1,COUNTIF($G$1,"*&*")),1,"")`

Comment: Be careful! to account for all the occurences at the beginning and at the end you need something like =COUNTIF(A1,"*&*")+COUNTIF(A1,"&*")+COUNTIF(A1,"*&") ...
but if you created a simple VBA function using "like" operator and used that one, it would work as you wish...

Answer (score 2):

`COUNTIFS` can also be used to test for multiple conditions:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1,"word1",A2,"word2")
```

word1, word2 may contain wildcard characters if required

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",$Q$1))," ",IF(I1=1,1,""))
```

or something like

```
=IF(AND(I1=1,NOT(ISERROR(FIND("&",$G$1)))),1," ")
```

any variation of that really...